# Blocked content in https

Tags: http, joomla, https

I have moved my Joomla website from one hoster to another and on the new hoster I get:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://mywebsite.com/joomla/media/jui/css/bootstrap.css"
```

I understand the reason: I use https, and browser detects a http call.

But how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- You change the source of your https website to point to the https version
- If you can't, you can fix it for moden browsers with that http header:

> Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

See https://scotthelme.co.uk/migrating-from-http-to-https-ease-the-pain-with-csp-and-hsts/

Note: to improve security, you should use HSTS. It will redirect http to https directly in the browser, without insecure redirect.

Specifically about joomla:
Did you set

> $live_site = 'https://www.your-domain.com';

in your configuration.php file ?
See https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/how-to-use-ssl-in-a-joomla-site

Comment: I have added this to index.html:
<http "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" "Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests"></http>
As ios developer this is not my cup of tea, so would this be correct?
I have also added the $live_site as suggested.
But browser still shows the same.

Comment: The headers must be set in your apache/nginx/whatever configuration file (.htaccess maybe?), not in your html file.